# onActivityResult data field null using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider

I have been trying to take a clear photo with the camera and pass it through intents to use it in the onActivityResult.

```
public void startCamera(View view) {
    //Start camera
    Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    output = new File(dir, "alphabetize.jpeg");
    camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", output));

    //Start onActivityResult to deal with the result
    startActivityForResult(camera, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //Todo REMOVE THIS BLOCK FOR TESTING vvvvvvvv
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", output), "image/jpeg");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            //Todo REMOVE THIS BLOCK FOR TESTING ^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
}
```

I am not encountering any errors, but the "i" intent for viewing the photo just gives a loading circle and the "data" field in onActivityResult is null.

I have been racking my brain searching and trying things over and over, but can't find anything.

I have found the issues with making my own FileProvider and already added this:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

to my Manifest and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

in an XML file title provider_paths.xml.
The request code and result code do match.
My target SDK is 26 and therefore cannot use Uri.fromFile without getting a FileUriExposedException.

It's a little messy, but I'm right at the beginning of making something and already hit a bit of an impasse! 
Thank you! Here's hoping it isn't just another missed semi-colon!

Comment: Is the photo actually placed in **alphabetize.jpeg**?

Comment: Oh! Good question. No, I don't believe so.

Comment: Ok, maybe the photo has been stored in some other file?

Comment: I think your **path attribute value** is incorrect. Try something like this 
"Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures"